# Does anyone know what does this status means: PON LED blinking and WAN Status No Carrier in Fiber Internet setup

Tags: networking, router, internet, fiber

My Internet connection from ISP is not working.
I have ZTE F670L ONT Router which is provided by my ISP in its Fiber internet setup.
When I check the WAN status it says `No carrier`

The PON LED on router is blinking continuously.

You may wonder why am I posting it here? No one in ISP is able to tell me what it means.
They may fix the issue with the help from backend team but the customer facing technicians don't have knowledge to answer this.

Does anyone know what does this status means: PON LED blinking and WAN Status `No Carrier` in Fiber Internet setup.

---

**Edit 1**: There's LOS LED as well but it is not glowing. It blinks Red only when I disconnect the fiber cable from the ONT, indicating complete loss of signal.

I live in an apartment complex where the same fiber junction box serves a number of apartments. I checked with neighbors, no one has any Internet issue at all. I have raised the issue with ISP but they are quite slow at taking action and no one is able to explain this kind of status or behavior of ONT.

Comment: No light on the fiber or not provisioned on the far end, basically it's not connecting to back to the CO... Possibly a bad ONT but unlikely, but these are usually supplied by the ISP anyway. Seems odd the ISP can't actually troubleshoot this, I would reach out to them again, this is most likely an ISP issue (something before it reached the ONT).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a publicly available manual for this model, but from what I can see, there should be LEDs for "PON" (Passive Optical Network, often used to indicate a low-level link and for activity), "LOS" (Loss of Signal) and "Internet" (often used to indicate an established high-level link). It's difficult to advise how these LEDs behave, but in my expereince, the "LOS" LED is typically lit only when the upstream signal has been lost.

If the "LOS" LED is not lit, then the "*No Carrier*" status is a bit misleading, any you may have a more complex issue with authentication and/or configuration on your ONT... best to get your ISP involved, re-issuing the ONT may be the easiest option.

If the "LOS" LED is lit, then paired with the "*No Carrier*" status you're reporting in the Web UI, would suggest that your ONT can't detect a valid signal from the OLT (at the ISP's end of the fibre).

This can be for a number of reasons ranging from simply being unplugged to a damaged / broken fibre anywhere between your equipment and their equipment, to equipment failure (at either your end or theirs).

The easiest thing for you to do, is check the fibre is indeed connected at both ends (to the wall termination and the ONT), and check it's not damaged and there are no signs of kinks or sharp bends through its full length.

If you're aware of neighbours who share the PON service, you could also try asking if their connection is still working - though I'd guess that due to the ISP's passive response, there isn't a known outage in your area, and this is unlikely.